# What is the struct for the handle to the main program returned by dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW)?

Tags: c, linux

According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) for `dlopen`:

> If filename is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main
>          program.

So my question is what is the structure for this handle to the main program and in what header is it located? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dlopen` return is an opaque `void *` pointer, but it really a pointer to a `struct link_map`.

You'll need to get the source to `glibc`. Look in the `elf` subdirectory and then the `link.h` file for a definition of `struct link`.

But, while you're there, look around a bit, and see how much code there is implement `dlopen`, `dlsym`, et. al. There are a number of other structs that you'll need to be concerned with. This is just the tip of the iceberg.

> For what I'm trying to achieve I've seen sample code which uses a pseudo structure to force proper memory alignment and access members.

It might help if you explained what you're trying to achieve as: *"These are not the droids you're looking for"*

I'm not sure what you mean by forcing proper memory alignment to access members. Why do you need to force alignment [and of what]? And, what members are you referring to?

Comment: Yep, it is a pointer to `struct link_map`, which is what I wanted to get to all along so that I can iterate over the list of shared objects. Thanks.

Comment: Just did more checking. `link.h` [and `elf.h`] are in `/usr/include`, so it may be easier. This also implies that while the original pointer is opaque, recasting it is a somewhat (i.e. expert level) supported action. Also, see `dl_interate_phdr`. At any rate, glibc's elf subdir has plenty of code that can serve as a guide

Comment: Excellent thanks `dl_iterate_phdr` is just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the `filename` is null or not, `dlopen` returns an opaque handle which can be passed to `dlsym` and `dlclose`.  You should not try to inspect the handle's data yourself.

Comment: Why not? For what I'm trying to achieve I've seen sample code which uses a pseudo structure to force proper memory alignment and access members. I'm curious about what the official structure looks like since I'd prefer to use this.